# Set Default Stylesheet Class for Images Uploaded using Django-CKEditor

Tags: django, ckeditor

I am using CK-Editor and Django (via django-ckeditor) to create a rich text field and upload images. However, some images are pretty large and I'd normally use bootstrap to make them responsive with the `image-fluid` class.

For Images uploaded with the CKEditor in Django I can set this class manually by going into `Image Properties > Advanced > Stylesheet Classes` and setting it to `image-fluid`. Is there any way to set this class as a default?

Currently I have tried the following in my settings.py with no luck:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'stylesSet': [
            {
                'name': 'Image-Fluid',
                'element': 'img',
                'attributes': {'class': 'img-fluid'},
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

Any idea if it is possible to set a deafult class for images uploaded using CKEditor? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code in `static/ckeditor/config.js`. Then do `python manage.py collectstatic`

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
   ev.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules(
    {
       elements:
        {
          $: function (element) {
            // check for the tag name
            if (element.name == 'img') {

                element.attributes.class = "img-fluid" // Put your class name here
            }

            // return element with class attribute
            return element;
         }
       }
   });
 });
```

Once you save the changes in editor after adding image, class name will reflect.

Comment: Hi, with your code, it seems that all <img> elements including emojis will have 'img-fluid' classname. Is there anyway to add classname to only the images but not emojis?

Comment: it seems not working if you install CKeditor with pip, so its a poor approch

Comment: This is working code and I did installed ckeditor using pip

Comment: how can we do this if we added ckeditor using php? i seems that we need to edit settings.py as seen in the question